# How do I compare $\ln(x)$ to $\ln(x - 1)$?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

When I was playing around with the formula for $\sin(\theta)$, I found out that $\ln(2i\sin(\theta)) = \ln(e^{2i\theta}-1) - i\theta$. Using common sense, I could derive that this would equal a little under $i\theta$. But I would like to know the exact value, so I was wondering if there was any way to compare $\ln(x)$ to $\ln(x - 1)$. I have tried asking [Wolfram Alpha](https://wolframalpha.com) and [Microsoft Math Solver](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com), but their output did not help.

Raw Wolfram Alpha input:
 ln(e^(2iθ)-1)-iθ

Raw Microsoft Maths Solver input (translated into raw input very weirdly):
   \log_{ e  }({  { e  }^{ 2i \theta    }  -1  })  -i \theta

(They're both the same equation.)

Comment: Could you include the inputs you passed along to WA and MMS?

Comment: Notice $\log(x) - \log(x - 1) = \log(\tfrac{x}{x - 1}) = \log(1 + \tfrac{1}{x-1})$. For instance using series expansions at that last step can give you good bounds if you don't want any more $\log$s.

Comment: @user170231 done

Comment: Are you sure your equality is correct?
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28e%5E%282iθ%29-1%29-iθ-ln%282i+sin%28θ%29%29

Comment: @AliAbbasinasab Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @prets That is not always true. The domain on which it is true will vary depending on your branch for the logarithm. The same point goes to the OP. $\log(2i\sin\theta)=\log(e^{2i\theta})-i\theta$ isn't necessarily true, it depends on your branch of logarithm and it should be carefully checked

Comment: @FShrike A very good point.

Comment: @FShrike My formula yields the same range of numbers as $\sin(x)$, namely between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: While the two sides are not necessarily equal, they always differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$ regardless of the branch of $\ln$ chosen.

Comment: Do you wanna move this discussion to chat?

Comment: For example, $\ln(2)-i\pi/2=\log(2i\sin(7\pi/2))\neq\pm\pi i-i7\pi/2=\log(e^{2i(7\pi/2)})-i(7\pi/2)$ if we are using the principal logarithm

Comment: WA agrees with the points made above. The imaginary parts do not always agree - see [the second plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot++ln%28e%5E%282i%CE%B8%29-1%29-i%CE%B8+and+ln%282i+sin%28theta%29%29+from+0+to+pi) (I think WA assumes a branch cut for the logarithm along the negative real axis, but I'm not 100% certain)

Comment: Counter example: =0. Does that help?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I am talking about the range where $\arcsin(\sin(\theta)) = \theta$

Comment: You also meant to say $\log(e^{2i\theta}-1)$, not $\log(e^{2i\theta})$

Comment: @FShrike Yes, correct.

Comment: I think you can improve the question because it's not true. You will get better answers. Do you see this counter example: =0?

Comment: Instead of doing an extended discussion here, we can chat about it in [this chat room I made](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144485/comparing-logx-to-logx-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you can use a Taylor series. The Taylor series relies on the fact that:
$$f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^n f'^n(x)}{n!}$$
where $f'^n(x)$ is the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$. To solve this, $x$ will be $x$ and $h$ will be $-1$. The Taylor series now becomes:
$$\ln([x+-1]=[x-1])=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\ln'^n(x)}{n!}$$
Writing out the sum gets:
$$\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{3x^3}-\frac{1}{4x^4}...$$
Noticing the pattern makes the sum:
$$\ln(x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{nx^n}$$
Therefore:
$$\ln(x-1)=\ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{nx^n}$$
Adapting this to the problem I had:
$$\ln(e^{2i\theta}-1)=2i\theta+\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{n \left(e^{2i\theta n}\right)}$$
So that is your answer.
If anyone else has a better one, they should feel free to post theirs!

Comment: Note that $$
\log (x - 1) = \log x + \log \left( {1 - \tfrac{1}{x}} \right)
$$ and use the Mercator series $\log(1+w)=w-\frac{w^2}{2}+\ldots$ with $w=-\frac{1}{x}$.